# Quartz plugin installed, but job is not starting in grails

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I just installed the quartz plugin(quartz2-0.2.2) and i am using grails-1.3.7.

Then I created my job-class using "grails create-job" and modified it for printing out a little message as test.

```
class ImportFilesJob {

    def startDelay = 100000L

    def cronExpression = "0 30 22 * * ?"

    def execute() {
        log.info"ImportFilesJob start!"
        println "ImportFilesJob start!"
        Date runDate = DateUtils.today
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis()
        log.info "Finished ImportFilesJob in ${end - start} millisec."
        println"Finished ImportFilesJob in ${end - start} millisec."
    }
}
```

Now, I'm expecting that job will start at 10.30pm every day.

But it is not so...

Do I miss something?

Thanx for any help.

Nimmy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forget the "trigger" block:

```
class MyFirstJob{
    def concurrent = false

    static triggers = {
        simple name: 'myFirstJobTrigger', startDelay: 1000, repeatInterval: 1000 }

    def group = "MyGroup"

    def execute(){ 
        println "MyFirstJob run!" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this in your "test"  environment?  If so Quartz is configured to not start automatically in test.  Check the QuartzConfig.groovy file and set

> autoStartup = true

And to check sooner that waiting until 10:30 you can use the following cron expression to kick it off every 3 minutes just to see that it is working:

> "0 0/3 * * * ?"

Comment: I have Quartz2DefaultConfig.groovy  environments {
    test {
        grails.plugin.quartz2.autoStartup = true
    }
}

Comment: Sorry - I'm not nearly as familiar with the Quartz2 plugin.